# Function to retrieve IDs of posts, cache results, and improve wp_query

Tags: wp-query, database, optimization

I'm looking to optimize db performance by creating a function that retrieves IDs of posts in a certain category and caches results. So instead of having a query like:

```
SELECT … WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( 
SELECT tr.object_id FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy               
AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'category' AND tt.term_id IN ('167') ) …
```

It becomes:

```
SELECT … WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN ( '1','2','3','4','5' ) …
```

I've read that get_objects_in_term() can be used for this. How would I construct this for a wp_query loop?

Comment: You could split that query into two queries, but what makes you think that would be more efficient? WordPress already caches quite a bit, by the way? Why are you asking about retrieving "IDs of posts in a certain category" when both of your queries are `NOT IN` queries which are the logical opposite of what you are asking (and are by nature not very efficient)?

Comment: The above query is an example. Have a look at https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1OXVFo1TSiz2jgIytsiUrLvBUiZztMl8FmYVIbUd_YdE/edit?pli=1#slide=id.g882f3d3_0_100 page 13.

Answer (score 1):

What the author of the article posted, as I read it, is suggesting you do is something like this:

```
$cats = array(1,2,3,4);
$q = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'category__not_in' => $cats
  )
);
var_dump($q->request);
```

You should see the complex default query in that dump.

```
$ids = array_unique(get_objects_in_term($cats,'category'));
var_dump($ids);
```

Now you have an array of post IDs for listed categories.

```
$q2 = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post__not_in' => $ids
  )
);
var_dump($q2->request);
```

Now you should see the more simple query that the author suggests.

If you look at the source for `get_objects_in_term()` you will about the same SQL as in the subquery of the first complex query:

```
$object_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT tr.object_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ($taxonomies) AND tt.term_id IN ($term_ids) ORDER BY tr.object_id $order");
```

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.1/src//wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L608

To get any gain from this you will have to cache `$ids`. There are two ways to do this: 1) is to use the [Transient API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient), which will give you time based caching, 2) the other is to [set/update options](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) on, say, post save so that you update `$ids` on the backend and your front end code never has to worry about the freshness of the cache.

I do not have time to write more of that code, but the caching part shouldn't be too hard given the Core code available and the Codex.